# Very slow system after installing 13.10?

Tags: performance

Just "upgraded" from 13.04 to 13.10 on my Acer C7 Ubuntu'd Chromebook and first thing I noticed is that everything is **very** slow and unresponsive. Hardly had this on 13.04. Opened system monitor to check processes and I saw that compiz is consistently using 20-80% of my CPU, even on idle. I tried installing Compizconfig, but it doesn't start up at all.

This is the final release, not a beta.  How can I make it more responsive - like it should be?

Comment: Please remember that you should ask a question. Do you want to ask how you can accelerate everything or how you can install ccsm? Did you install a beta-version or the stable release? Did you recognise such a behaviour in the past?

Comment: Dear mr Lehmann
My question is posed in the title and goes "how do I solve the unresponsiveness of Ubuntu in 13.10"
Yes, it is a stable release, the official one. Upgraded through the Software Centre. 13.04 ran very well for me.

Answer (score 4):

Switching the [acceleration method](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Choose_acceleration_method) from SNA to the old UXA worked for me:

place the following lines in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (create it if it doesn't exist, you will need root privileges to edit the file):

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
#Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

Source: http://linuxg.net/fix-slow-graphics-performance-on-ubuntu-13-04-intel-gpu/

Comment: Weird but true! The new SNA acceleration may score more in games/benchmarks but after switching to UXA the UI became noticeably faster (e.g. rendering tabs in browsers, switching windows, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Asus laptop. During the upgrade, the native video driver was removed and not re-installed. Try reinstalling the video driver.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

And restart your display manager or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the upgrade changed my GRUB default menu entry from 3.11.x to 3.5.x, which forced the use of llvmpipe/Gallium software graphics rendering. Editing /etc/default/grub (after getting the right string from `grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg  | grep 3.11`) and then running `sudo update-grub` fixed it.

Before figuring this out, I had tried adding `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`, installing some `fglrx`, `fglrx-pxpress`, `nvidia-319`, `nvidia-prime`, and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` packages, and conversely removing the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` and `xserver-xorg-video-vmware` packages. None of these were improvements; some were notable degradations.

Some additional info:

```
tsbertalan@flapjack:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

tsbertalan@flapjack:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy

tsbertalan@flapjack:~$ uname -a
Linux flapjack 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Things are ok now:

```
tsbertalan@flapjack:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p | grep -v yes
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.0-devel (git-16215a9 saucy-oibaf-ppa+curaga)
```